# why all div inside php tag not work

Tags: php

WHy all div inside php tag not work

```
<body>
<div class="main-section ">
        <?php
             $result=$restaurant->runQuery("SELECT fooditem.*,restaurant.* from fooditem ,restaurant ,foodcategory where restaurant.restaurantID=foodcategory.restaurantID and foodcategory.categoryID=fooditem.categoryID and restaurant.restaurantID='$id' ");
                                if (!empty($result))  
                                            foreach($result as $value){
                                                ?>

    <div class="page-content-fullwidth">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

        echo "<div class="page-section restaurant-detail-image-section" style="background: url(../../wp-content/uploads/cover-photo12.jpg) no-repeat scroll 0 0 / cover">"
       <?php  }?>
```

Background image will be display when foreach bracket cut from this position

Comment: What you mean by "not work"? How a HTML tag can "not work"?

Comment: As i suppose It will be throwing a parse error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues:

- Your foreach loop contains 4 opening div-tags - but you don't close them. This will result in a faulty markup.
- The `echo` will not work without `<?php`-tags around.
- You could remove the `echo` anyways because you're not printing any variables
- The `if` is missing curly braces. You can only miss them if your content is no longer than one line or in the same line.
- Also consider using Alternative syntax for control structures: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php
- Because your answer does not have any further information, I suspect you don't have error_reporting/display_errors enabled. So maybe this would be very helpful for developing.

So fixed it should look like this:

```
<body>
<div class="main-section ">
    <?php
    $result = $restaurant->runQuery("SELECT fooditem.*,restaurant.* from fooditem ,restaurant ,foodcategory where restaurant.restaurantID=foodcategory.restaurantID and foodcategory.categoryID=fooditem.categoryID and restaurant.restaurantID='$id' ");
    if (!empty($result)):
        foreach($result as $value): ?>

    <div class="page-content-fullwidth">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="page-section restaurant-detail-image-section" style="background: url(../../wp-content/uploads/cover-photo12.jpg) no-repeat scroll 0 0 / cover"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```